# Derivation is sens of distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

We consider the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(x)
=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin x}{2} &: x \in ]-\infty,\dfrac{\pi}{2}[\\
0 &: x \in [\dfrac{\pi}{2},+\infty[
\end{cases}
$$
The questions are:

1. calculate $(T_f)'$,
2. calculate $(T_f)''$,
3. deduce the differential equation satisfied by $(T_f)'$ and $(T_f)''$.

My solution is:

$f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$, so we can define the distribution $T_f$ by the relation

$$
\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}), \langle T_f,\varphi \rangle = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \varphi(x) dx= \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\sin x}{2} \varphi (x) dx.
$$

1. Calclulate $(T_f)'$: we have 
   $$
   (T_f)'= T_{f'} + (f(\dfrac{\pi}{2}^+) - f(\dfrac{\pi}{2}^-)) \delta_{\pi/2}
   =
   \dfrac{1}{2} \cos(x) + \delta_{\pi/2}.
   $$

My problem is: How I can calculate $(T_f)''$? with an rule for example, and how we deduce the differential equation satisfied by $(T_f)'$ and $(T_f)''$? Please.

Comment: What is $T$????

Comment: i edit my first post. Thank you for advice.

Comment: There are two problems  with your $T'_f$: first, you forgot that $\frac \sin x$ was used only for $x<\pi/2$, second, the coefficient at $\delta_{\pi/2}$ is not $1$.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\langle T',\phi\rangle=-\langle T,\phi'\rangle=-\frac12\int_{\pi/2}^\infty(\sin x)\,\phi'(x)\,dx=\frac12\int_{\pi/2}^\infty(\cos x)\,\phi(x)\,dx+\frac12\,\phi(\pi/2).
$$
Now for the second derivative:
$$\begin{align}
\langle T'',\phi\rangle&=-\langle T',\phi'\rangle&\\
&=-\frac12\int_{\pi/2}^\infty(\cos x)\,\phi'(x)\,dx-\frac12\,\phi'(\pi/2)\\
&=-\frac12\int_{\pi/2}^\infty(\sin x)\,\phi(x)\,dx-\frac12\,\phi'(\pi/2).
\end{align}$$
Thus $T''=-T+\dfrac12\,\delta_{\pi/2}'$.